# convert time GMT to UTC

Tags: python, time, strptime

I am trying to convert a time that I receive with GMT time but I render details by time format using strptime.

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

ZERO = timedelta(0)

class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    """Fixed UTC offset: `local = utc + offset`."""

    def __init__(self, offset, name):
        self.__offset = timedelta(hours=offset)
        self.__name = name

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.__offset

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.__name

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO

utc = FixedOffset(0, "UTC")
```

The following code shows the data that I want to convert.

```
Time = ("14:50:21.000 GMT Fri Apr 29 2022")
dt = datetime.strptime(Time , "%H:%M:%% GMT %% %% %% %%")
aware = dt.replace(tzinfo=FixedOffset(5, "GMT 0"))
print(aware)                 
print(aware.astimezone(utc))
```

Return the message

```
ValueError: time data '14:50:21.000 GMT Fri Apr 29 2022' does not match format '%H:%M:%% GMT %% %% %% %%'
```

Comment: "strptime" interprets double percent sign as one literal percent sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%%` is used for the % character witch is not in your source time format try this format

```
dt = datetime.strptime(Time , "%H:%M:%S GMT %a %b %d %Y")
```

or

```
dt = datetime.strptime(Time , "%H:%M:%S %Z %a %b %d %Y")
```

you can read more [here](https://strftime.org/) on how the format argument is formulated

Comment: thank you,

It worked for me, but as I receive the seconds with more information, it indicates the same error for this.

Time= ("14:50:21.000 GMT Fri Apr 29 2022")


I have tried the following ways

%H:%M:%S.%j %Z %a %b %d %Y
%H:%M:%S.%z %Z %a %b %d %Y

Comment: Final use the next format "%H:%M:%S.%f %Z %a %b %d %Y"